# react-native run-ios fails to build

Tags: xcode, macos, react-native

I have an existing project, that have been tested on an windows + android setup. Now I'm trying to run it on a macbook to test on an Iphone 11 simulator.

- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.64.0

I install the pod file and try to run

`react-native run-ios`

I get a the following error:

> ** BUILD FAILED **

> The following build commands failed:
> CompileC [USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/andon-hkuetryxdipcrgbcxnseaqnfnaqp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTTurboModuleManager.o [PROJECT_PATH]/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/react/nativemodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm normal x86_64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
> (1 failure)

Comment: Do you install Xcode? If you installed Xcode, you try to execute it after cloning the project again.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this problem while running a React Native iOS app on macOS. After researching the issue for hours I was able to resolve it with these steps:

1. Clear the cache of `pod` by running these commands:

   `rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods`

   `rm -rf Pods`

   `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*`

   `pod deintegrate`

   `pod setup`
2. Navigate to the ios directory, and delete the `Pods` directory
3. While still in the ios directory, run `pod install`
4. Navigate back to the project directory, and run `npx react-native run-ios`

Hope this helps you too!

Answer (score 1):

Probably very late to answer.

I started facing this issue after I upgraded from `0.63.4` to `0.64.2`.

If we run from command line was not getting any way to find out the error. When I ran from x-code, found following error message,

> /node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/react/nativemodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm:172:8: 'shared_timed_mutex' is unavailable: introduced in iOS 10.0

The reason for that was the following entry in my podfile,

> config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'

After I deleted the above entry it started working like a charm.

ref: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31250#issuecomment-808312355

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]

- Under XCode top menu,  Goto XCode->Preferences -> Locations -> Open
  Derived Data folder(By clicking the arrow button) (Find screenshot
  for your references)
- Finder will open Derived Data folder,
- Delete Derived Data Folder
- Start Metro server using npm start or yarn start
- Perform Clean build using cmd+shift+k
- Run the application using cmd+r

Comment: What if I have made the project in VSC and the build still fails after your fix?
I try to run the code in VSC with react-native run-ios

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to build react native project in iOS with this issue. And I did build after following processes.

1- Clear the cache of pod with

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
pod deintegrate
pod setup
```

2- And delete the project's Pods directory. The location of it is project directory > ios > Pods.
3- Then in the project directory > ios location, install pod with pod install
4- And npx react-native run-ios in project directory

This is worked for me perfectly...
for more information you can check [this link in github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26118#issuecomment-525085809)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is recurring, especially in the compatibility that macOS has with react native, but everything has a solution, sometimes forced, but there is a solution.

```
In your ios folder (ios cd) execute the following steps.

rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods

rm -rf Pods

rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*

pod deintegrate

pod setup
```

After you have done this, execute:

```
pod install
```

Continue with yarn install or npm install to run metro, if metro does not open, the application will not open.

After these steps, run npx react-native run-ios, the app should open, in case it does not open and gives you an error, open it directly from the simulator and do the building.

I will continue looking for solutions and exposing them.

PD: If my English is poor, excuse me, I am from Chile and I am learning the language.

Comment: This answer is virtually identical to @Green’s answer from two years ago, and especially the initial steps. What new value do you believe this is providing beyond what they already proposed?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, if you read carefully it is not "identical" to @Green's answer. While the code flow is similar, the subsequent steps are not. There is a possibility that metro will not be built automatically, a critical step to run the application. After that step, there is another possibility to build the application directly from the simulator, which will do an automatic build. Please read carefully before answering. Thank you.